# Casperjs - Error with script to login on https website

Tags: javascript, https, casperjs, autologin

I Have a problem with a script to login on my https website.

The script :

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
console.log("casper create OK");

casper.start("https://my-ip/login_page.html", function() {
console.log("Connexion URL OK");

    // set a wait condition to make sure the page is loaded (particularly iframe in my case) 
    this.wait(5000,function(){
    console.log("Attente 5 sec OK");

        //fill out the form 
        this.fillSelectors("form[name='lf']",{
            'input#user' : "my_login",
            'input#pass' : "my_password"
        });
        console.log("Renseignement login et pass OK");

        // click the login button 
        this.click("input[name='loginsub']");
        console.log("Passage bouton login OK");

        // switch to iframe (won't be necessary for most)
        this.page.switchToChildFrame('mainframe');
        console.log("Switch iframe OK");

            // Test d'une zone sur la page pour valider la connexion
            casper.waitForSelector('.area-status', function() {
            console.log("Validation element sur la page OK");
            });
    }); 
});
// Check etat de l'alarme général
// Check status des zones de l'alarme

casper.run();
```

And the return :

```
[root@srv-linux bin]# casperjs test.js
casper create OK
Connexion URL OK
Attente 5 sec OK
CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: form not found
  /tmp/casperjs/modules/casper.js:807 in fillForm
  /tmp/casperjs/modules/casper.js:897 in fillSelectors
  /usr/local/bin/test.js:14
  /tmp/casperjs/modules/casper.js:2052 in _check
[root@srv-linux bin]# casperjs fe.js
SyntaxError: Parse error
```

The problem is after function wait.
The form name is "lf" I have check this :

```
<form name="lf" action="default.html" method="get" onsubmit="return loginencrypt();">
```

I try to take a capture after wait 5sec but my png is blank...

Have you any ideas?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, execute script with this ssl options :

```
casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes test4.js
```